# F# Async completion source?

Tags: f#

I want an `async` to wait for a value to be provided. C# has a mechanism for doing this in tasks, but I am using `async`.

Here is what I came up with:

```ml
type AsyncCompletionSource<'t>() =
  let tcs = TaskCompletionSource<'t>()

  with
    member this.Set(x : 't) =
      tcs.SetResult(x)

    member this.Get 
      with get () = 
        Async.AwaitTask tcs.Task
```

I was wondering if there is something already provided for this in F#?

And if not, is there a way to accomplish this without jumping in and out of `task`?

---

Also called: future, promise, settable future, subject

Comment: What's wrong with `TaskCompletionSource` itself?

Comment: Nothing for my use-case, mostly curious. I suppose Fable users might want a pure async solution.

Comment: Oh, I see, you wanted without `Task`. But actually, this is just a mutable cell, isn't it? Or is it different from a mutable cell somehow?

Comment: The challenge is getting an Async to wait on the cell being set

Comment: Ah, something like [`MVar`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-19.2/base-4.15.1.0/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html)?

Comment: Use FusionTasks to have a seamless interop